# How can I undo value updates in an MUI datagrid?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

I have some hardcoded table data in the grid and Value and Notes column is editable. I am trying to add an Undo/Redo feature that is triggered by a button click. I have a stack that keeps track of the previous states but when i try to pop the states from the stack and set it as the rows it does not update the values in the app. I still see the new value in the table view even after forceUpdate() is called using the apiRef.

How can I implement undo feature and have the table view show the new values?

Here is my code:

```
const columns: GridColDef[] = [
    { field: 'cost', headerName: 'Costs', width: 300 },
    { field: 'value', headerName: 'Value', width: 130, editable: true },

    {
        field: 'date',
        headerName: 'Date',
        type: 'date',
        width: 130,
    },
    {
        field: 'fullName',
        headerName: 'User',
        sortable: false,
        width: 160,
        
    },
    {
        field: 'notes',
        headerName: 'Notes',
        width: 160,
        editable: true
     }
];

var rowsMSRtable = [
    {
        id: 1,
        cost: 'Share Cost',
        value: '$20',
        date: new Date('February 10, 2023 02:30:00'),
        fullName: 'John Smith',
        notes: '',
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        cost: 'Billing Cost',
        value: '$50',
        date: new Date('February 10, 2023 02:30:00'),
        fullName: 'John Smith',
        notes: '',
    }
];

var undoStack: { id: number; cost: string; value: string; date: Date; fullName: string; notes: string; }[][] = [];
var gridMSRHook = useGridApiRef();

const undo = () => {
   
    if(undoStack.length === 0){
        console.log('Nothing left to undo');
           }else{
      var popped = undoStack.pop();
      
      if(popped != undefined){
        rowsMSRtable = popped; //this does not work
    gridMSRHook.current.forceUpdate();

      }
    
    }
    
  };


return(
<IconButton aria-label="undo" onClick={undo}>
                                <UndoOutlinedIcon />
                            </IconButton>


<DataGrid
                    rows={rowsMSRtable}
                    columns={columns}
                    initialState={{
                        pagination: {
                            paginationModel: { page: 0, pageSize: 100 },
                        },
                    }}
                    pageSizeOptions={[1]}
                    hideFooterPagination
                    checkboxSelection
                    
                    apiRef={gridMSRHook}
                    onCellEditStart={() => {
                      if(undoStack.length == 20){
                        undoStack.shift(); 
                      }
                      undoStack.push(rowsMSRtable);
                      
                      console.log(undoStack);
                      console.log('EDIT START');
                    }}
                   
                    
                    
                />
);
```

I have tried using apiRef.current.exportState() in the stack and restoreState() and then forceUpdate(),
and tried pushing only the edited row into the stack then using rowsMSRtable[popped.id-1].value = popped.value
none of them work, the table does not update to the previous values.